No routes matched location "/" and searchbar, pagination and filter not displaying. React.js
When i added the searchbar logic, the pagination and the filter, I got the error "No routes matched location "/"". I'm using Postman to test if the logic is right and it works, but for some reason the elements aren't displaying. I think the error might be in the routing but it looks fine to me.
App.js where the routing is:
import Login from './components/user/Login';

const alertOptions = {
  position: positions.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  timeout: 5000,
  offset: '30px',
  transition: transitions.SCALE
};

function App() {
  return (
    <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <div className="container container-fluid">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
              <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} exact />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AlertProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Home.js component where the filter and pagination are supposed to be displayed:
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";
import Slider from "rc-slider";
import "rc-slider/assets/index.css";
import MetaData from "./layout/MetaData";
import Product from "./product/Product";
import Loader from "./layout/Loader";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getProducts } from "../actions/productActions";

const Home = () => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([0, 1000]);
  const { keyword } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading, products, error, productsCount, resPerPage } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.products
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      return alert.error(error);
    }

    dispatch(getProducts(keyword, currentPage, price));
  }, [dispatch, error, keyword, currentPage, price]);

  function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title={"Buy the best plugins for FL Studio!"} />
          <h1 id="products-heading"></h1>
          <section id="products" className="container mt-5">
            <div className="row">
              {keyword ? (
                <Fragment>
                  <div className="col-6 col-md-3 mt-5 mb-5">
                    <div className="px-5">
                      {}
                      <Slider.Range
                        marks={{
                          0: "0",
                          1000: "1000",
                        }}
                        min={0}
                        max={1000}
                        defaultValue={[0, 1000]}
                        tipFormater={(value) => value}
                        tipProps={{
                          placement: "top",
                          visible: true,
                        }}
                        value={price}
                        onChange={(price) => setPrice(price)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-6 col-md-9">
                    <div className="row">
                      {products.map((product) => (
                        <Product key={product._id} product={product} col={4}/>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Fragment>
              ) : (
                products.map((product) => (
                  <Product key={product._id} product={product} col={3}/>
                ))
              )}
            </div>
          </section>
          {resPerPage <= currentPage && (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
              <Pagination
                activePage={currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
                totalItemsCount={productsCount}
                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                nextPageText={"Next"}
                prevPageText={"Previous"}
                firstPageText={"First"}
                lastPageText={"Last"}
                itemClass="page-item"
                linkClass="page-link"
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Home;

getProducts from productActions.js:
export const getProducts = (keyword = '',currentPage = 1, price) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST });

        let link = `/api/v1/products?keyword=${keyword}&page=${currentPage}&price[lte]=${price[1]}&price[gte]=${price[0]}`
        const {data} = await axios.get(link);

        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        });
    }
};

Search.js for the searchbar:
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Search = ({history}) => {
    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('')
    const searchHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if(keyword.trim()){
            history.pushState(`/search/${keyword}`)
        } else {
            history.pushState('/')
        }
    }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="search_field"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Пакети, инструментали, плъгини..."
              onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button id="search_btn" className="btn">
                <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
  )
}
export default Search

And Header.js where the searchbar is:
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Search from './Search';
import { Link , Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import "../../App.css";

const Header = ({product}) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <nav className="navbar row">
        <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
          <Link to={'/'}>
            <div className="navbar-brand">
              <img
                src="/images/Logo.png"
                style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
                alt=""
              />
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <Routes>
            <Route render={({history}) => <Search history={history} />} />
        </Routes>
        </div>

        <div className="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center">
          <Link to="/login" className="btn ml-4" id="login_btn">
            Регистрация
          </Link>
          <span id="cart" className="ml-3">
            Количка
          </span>
          <span className="ml-1" id="cart_count">
            2
          </span>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Header;

Sidenote I just tried the Login and it kind of works. In redux devtools it says that logging is is successful but then I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"
Login.js
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { login, clearErrors } from "../../actions/userActions";

const Login = ({ history }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const alert = useAlert();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      history.push("/");
    }

    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, isAuthenticated, error, history]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title={"Login"} />

          <div className="row wrapper">
            <div className="col-10 col-lg-5">
              <form className="shadow-lg" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <h1 className="mb-3" style={{color:'#8da1ea'}}>Login</h1>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="email_field" style={{color:'#8da1ea'}}>Email</label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    id="email_field"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="password_field" style={{color:'#8da1ea'}}>Password</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password_field"
                    className="form-control"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                  />
                </div>

                <Link to="/password/forgot" className="float-right mb-4" style={{color:'#8da1ea'}}>
                  Forgot Password?
                </Link>

                <button
                  id="login_button"
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-block py-3"
                >
                  LOGIN
                </button>

                <Link to="/register" className="float-right mt-3" style={{color:'#8da1ea'}}>
                  New User?
                </Link>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;

I hope this code is enough. Thank you in advance!

You appear to be using React-Router-DOM (RRD) v6. RRDv6 has a ton of breaking API changes from the older v4/5. Routes no longer have route props, so if you are trying to access the old history route prop you should instead now use the useNavigate hook and access the navigate function.

I don't see any issue in the Home component that would prevent the "/" route from being accessible, but you can remove the exact prop on the Route components. All routes are now always exactly matched in RRDv6.
function App() {
  return (
    <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Header />
          <div className="container container-fluid">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/search/:keyword" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AlertProvider>
  );
}


Fix Search and Header to use the useNavigate hook and render routes correctly. The routes that Header renders is what actually causes the error message you see since there is no "/" route rendered. Since Search can access the navigate function directly there's no need to try and pass "history" from the old route props down as props. Remove the descendent routes in Header and render Search directly.
Search
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const searchHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    navigate(keyword ? `/search/${keyword}` : "/");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={searchHandler}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="search_field"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Пакети, инструментали, плъгини..."
          onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value.trim())}
        />
        <div className="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" id="search_btn" className="btn">
            <i className="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Search;

Header
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Search from './Search';
import { Link , Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../App.css";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar row">
      <div className="col-12 col-md-3">
        <Link to="/">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <img
              src="/images/Logo.png"
              style={{ width: "100px", height: "100px" }}
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-6 mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <Search />
      </div>

      <div className="col-12 col-md-3 mt-4 mt-md-0 text-center">
        <Link to="/login" className="btn ml-4" id="login_btn">
          Регистрация
        </Link>
        <span id="cart" className="ml-3">
          Количка
        </span>
        <span className="ml-1" id="cart_count">
          2
        </span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;


Similarly fix Login component's usage of "history".
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader";
import MetaData from "../layout/MetaData";
import { login, clearErrors } from "../../actions/userActions";

const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const alert = useAlert();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { isAuthenticated, error, loading } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.auth
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }

    if (error) {
      alert.error(error);
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }
  }, [dispatch, alert, isAuthenticated, error, navigate]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(login(email, password));
  };

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <MetaData title={"Login"} />

      <div className="row wrapper">
        <div className="col-10 col-lg-5">
          <form className="shadow-lg" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
            <h1 className="mb-3" style={{ color: '#8da1ea' }}>
              Login
            </h1>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="email_field" style={{ color: '#8da1ea' }}>
                Email
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email_field"
                className="form-control"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password_field" style={{ color: '#8da1ea' }}>
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password_field"
                className="form-control"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>

            <Link
              to="/password/forgot"
              className="float-right mb-4"
              style={{ color: '#8da1ea' }}
            >
              Forgot Password?
            </Link>

            <button
              id="login_button"
              type="submit"
              className="btn btn-block py-3"
            >
              LOGIN
            </button>

            <Link
              to="/register"
              className="float-right mt-3"
              style={{ color: '#8da1ea' }}
            >
              New User?
            </Link>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Login;



